# How can I apply styling to ngb-timepicker (timpicker for angular by boostrap) buttons?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using ngb-timepicker to get time from user.
but the time buttons(arrowkeys) are having arrow cursor as default.
I want to style the arrow keys to have pointer as the cursor.

html:

`<ngb-timepicker class="picker" [(ngModel)]="time1" required></ngb-timepicker>`

css:

`.picker button.btn-link{
 cursor:pointer;
 }`

Comment: For me the arrowkeys in the timepicker have the cursor pointer in their [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples) examples. Does your example differ from the documentation or am I missunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

```
:host /deep/ ngb-timepicker {
}
```

For example, to alter the height of the inputs you would use:

```
:host /deep/ ngb-timepicker input {
   height: 45px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to put your style in the global style sheet `styles.css` or `styles.scss`

Comment: But not always the best solution, as you might only need it for a certain component.  So if it's in the styles.css you are loading it all the time when you might not even need it.

Comment: Another solution is to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the component that is using the ngb-timepicker you can then add the desired style to the component stylesheet. However, this setting will make all the css from the component stylesheet available globally